# Why am I getting client fetch error when i have NEXTAUTH_URL properly set?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, backend, credentials, next-auth

### I have authentication based on credential provider in my nexJs app.I am constantly getting client fetch error. I have tried everything available here, I cant fix the error. Please help!

The error seem to be with .env.local file but I added all the files that maybe contributing to the error. Thankyou very much for your time.

```
//This api posts to a table in nextJS that has one to one relationship with the user table used by the credentials provider of next-auth.
import connectMongo from '../../../connection/conn';
import table from '../../../model/new'
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"

  export default async function handler(req, res){

    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    connectMongo().catch(error =>  res.json({ error: "Connection Failed...!"}))

    // only post method is accepted
    if(req.method === 'POST'){
    

        if(!req.body) return res.status(404).json({ error: "Don't have form data...!"});
        
        const {
            
            FirstName,
            MiddleName,
            LastName,
            PhoneNo,
            DOB,
            Email,
            State,
            District
          
           
           
          } = req.body;
          const session = await getSession({ req });
        if (!session) {
          res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
          return;
        }
        const user = session.user._doc.id;
  
        console.log(req.body);

        

        
        table.create({FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,PhoneNo,DOB,Email,State,District,user},                function(err, data){
            if(err) return res.status(404).json({ err });
            return res.status(201).json({ status : true, user: data})
            
        })

    } else{
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "HTTP method not valid only POST Accepted"})
    }
    

}
```

```
//.env.local file
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
#NEXTAUTH_JWT_SECRET=685379d7c40ae29c256b274ada57a9f6
SECRET="WnRizN9Yk5Tw8VVSdHaEQrKf8Z1c50V2Se7GM9NWr1E="


MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://rishi:loser@cluster0.fs6n3qi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

### This is the [nextauth.ts] file

```
import NextAuth,{ NextAuthOptions }  from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import connectMongo from '../../../../connection/conn'
import Users from '../../../../model/Schema'
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';
import clientPromise from "./lib/mongodb"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
]
    CredentialsProvider({
      name : "Credentials",
       credentials: {
         username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
         password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
       },
      async authorize(credentials, req){
          connectMongo().catch(error => { error: "Connection Failed...!"})
          
          // check user existance
          const result = await Users.findOne( { username :credentials.username})
          console.log(result)
          if(!result){
              throw new Error("No user Found with Email Please Sign Up...!")
          }

          // compare()
          const checkPassword = await compare(credentials.password, result.password);
          console.log(checkPassword)
          // incorrect password
          if(!checkPassword || result.username !== credentials.username){
              throw new Error("Username or Password doesn't match");
          }

          return result;

      }
      }),
    ],
     session: {
       jwt: true,
  },
   
      secret: process.env.SECRET,
      callbacks:{
      async jwt({ token, user }) {
       return {...token, ...user}
        },
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
        
         
          session.user = token;
          console.log(session.user);
        
        return session;
      }
     
      
 }
 }
}
  
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

```
#This is the complete error.
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
```